# Compare Columns, Highlight Missing Values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I am looking to compare two columns, a "Roster" column and a "Present" column and highlight any missing values.

The "Roster" column is a fixed value, but the "Present" column is a formula matching a name to an attendance code.

I have tried countif, unique, match, and pretty much every other type of formula to make this work, but I cannot get it working properly. I have attached a sample worksheet below, any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ahEWyD37adWIiLG3CCuIfEmgAdlYXvkFaIAWIHGe_Y/edit?usp=sharing

(I have this working in Excel with Conditional Formatting and Unique Values but Google Sheets is another beast).

Comment: Welcome! Please try Conditional Format for range **C3:C8** with custom formula `=(COUNTIF($B$3:$B$8,C3)=0)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! I am unable to get the formula to produce the formatting, and have attached a screenshot below. I'm frustrated since this should be so simple! If need be I am willing to allow access to this sheet for any troubleshooting. Cheers! 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vpyk9VycUAb_9DADqUkU2AI77_E3mr_7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's a formula! Formula starts with **=** sign:  change to `=(COUNTIF($B$3:$B$8,C3)=0)` :-)

Comment: Oh. My. Gosh. I cannot believe this. The first time I added in the = sign it gave me an error so I figured I did something wrong. I go back and add it now, realizing I missed the last closed paranthesis. I cannot thank you enough, Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

### Use MATCH

You can use match to look at the list of scanned numbers and color the roster names if their id number is not matched.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ahEWyD37adWIiLG3CCuIfEmgAdlYXvkFaIAWIHGe_Y

**Conditional Formatting Custom Formula:**

```
    =IFERROR(MATCH($D3,$A$3:$A$26,0)<1,TRUE)   // TRUE if no match
```